# JavaFx resizable

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making an javafx application that needs to be maximized, and not resizable.
(I have to see the taskbar under the window, but I have fixed that).
But when I set this:

```
spelStage.setResizable(false);
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
spelStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
spelStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
spelStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
spelStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
```

It shows the way I want it (because with setMaximize(true) the taskbar disappears). But when you drag on the titlebar it still resizes the window smaller despites I say resizable false...

Any tips on how to make the window not resizable at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Screens please, I cannot clearly picture what happens and what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Yeah sure, sorry..  With the code above: http://imgur.com/jbsJjG4; With setMaximize(true) (without Rectangle -> getheight) http://imgur.com/6DqGlGB and when I doubleclick the titlebar when it's maximized: http://imgur.com/FZRGaFU. I cleared the content of the windows because it's school related. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to make window not resizeable then you can set `resizeable` property on stage to `false`:

```
spelStage.setResizable(false);
```

Please note that the window could still be moved by dragging titlebar.

This problem would be probably gone if you additionaly set window style to `UNDECORATED`:

```
spelStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Comment: I believe typing Alt+space will allow an undecorated Stage to be resized.

Comment: @VGR not on Windows 7 with Java 1.8.0_45, but I'll edit answer - I don't know how could it work on other systems - thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: I just checked, and you're right.  It appears resizing is truly disabled for undecorated Stages.

Comment: I marked this as used answer, I don't think there is any other way then to go with undecorated window. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @RockTheStar can you provide a sample code which does not work in this way?